# get id of element that triggered bootstrap modal hide

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap modal that has several elements that trigger hide event on click. I want to get the id of element that triggered the event at time.

I tried to use `event.target` as well as `event.relatedTarget` but both are not working.

code for modal is

```
<div id="GSCCModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;  </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="max-width: 300px;">
    <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-dismiss="modal" id='link1'>Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-dismiss="modal" id='link2'>Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-dismiss="modal" id='link3'>Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id='btn1' type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

while js code is

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#GSCCModal', function (event) {
  var target = $(event.relatedTarget);
  console.log(target.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the script as follows

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#GSCCModal', function (event) {
  var id = $(this).attr("id") == undefined ? "NO-ID" : $(this).attr("id") ;
  console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: mmm... the solution you posted will return the id of modal itself... I want id of  element that closed the modal. Like if I click close button and modal hides, I should get 'btn1' as result.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this by giving common class to all the elements which triggers modal hide and using their click event.

```
<div id="GSCCModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;  </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="max-width: 300px;">
    <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-dismiss="modal" id='link1' class="close">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-dismiss="modal" id='link2' class="close">Link 2</a></li>
    <li"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-dismiss="modal" id='link3' class="close">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id='btn1' type="button" class="btn btn-default close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and js is

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.close').on('click', function(event) {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
});
```